# Adsense for android : sample ad units or test ads on test device?

Tags: android, admob, adsense

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads) there are two different ways to test ads on an Android app :

- Sample ad units (generic public ad unit ID) : empty banner
- Test ads (with your real ad unit ID but declaring the device as test) : real banner with "Test ad" label

I got both working but I wonder if one is better than the other to develop and test.
Is it discouraged to use test ads instead of sample ads during the development process?
Is there any risk to display a lot of test ads?

If not, it seems to be simpler to keep the real ad unit ID in the code and set the emulator/test-device as a test device, so you don't have any change to do between development and release versions.

Answer (score 0):

Sample ads is so easy and save to use. Make use of the ternary operator with BuildConfig field.

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" : "yourRealAdUnitID");
```